# How to apply Height and Width attributes to CkEditor5 inserted Image

Tags: jquery, ckeditor5

I have a CkEditor5 template used to send emails. When an Image is inserted to the editor and resized, it adds a style tag with width in percentage (%). As outlook doesn't support style tag and need to add Height and Width attributes.

Managed to add Height and Width attributes to inserted image via Jquery but editor.GetData() not considering any style/attributes updated by JQuery script.
Also tried editor.updateSourceElement after updating attributes via JQuery but no success.
Is there any way we can update CkEditor5 elements via Jquery and commit changes to underlying editor so editor.GetData will return updated html?